# Utilizar Promise.all ou prisma.$transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Prisma e Nestjs, me surgiu uma dúvida em qual a melhor forma de trabalhar com as promises para que não perca desempenho.

O Prisma possui o `$transaction` para realizar múltiplas querys, porém estou usando o `Promise.all` para fazer duas consultas, exemplo:

Tenha um módulo Bairro, nele estão os seguintes arquivos.

bairro.controller.ts

```
export class BairroController {
    constructor(
        private readonly bairroService: BairroService,
    ) {}

    @Get()
    async findMany() {

        const [data, count] = await Promise.all([
            this.bairroService.findMany(),
            this.bairroService.count()
        ])

        return {
            data,
            count
        }
    }
}
```

bairro.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class BairroService {
    constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}

    async findMany(): Promise<Bairro[]> {
        return await this.prisma.bairro.findMany()
    }

    async count(): Promise<number> {
        return await this.prisma.bairro.count()
    }

    async findOne(id: number): Promise<Bairro> {
        return await this.prisma.bairro.findFirst({
            where: { id_bairro: id },
        })
    }

    async create(data: CreateBairroDto): Promise<void> {
        await this.prisma.bairro.create({
            data,
        })
    }

    async update(id: number, data: UpdateBairroDto): Promise<void> {
        await this.prisma.bairro.update({
            where: { id_bairro: id },
            data,
        })
    }

    async delete(id: number): Promise<void> {
        await this.prisma.bairro.delete({ where: { id_bairro: id } })
    }
}
```

Somente no controller eu chamo o Promise.all para que seja feita a consulta nos findMany e count, queria saber se essa seria a melhor forma de fazer.

Tendo em vista que eu poderia fazer com que o service me retorne um objeto contendo `{data, count}`, assim eu usaria o $transaction do Prisma direto no método findMany do service.

Qual a forma correta de utilizar? Tendo em vista para obter desempenho e também ter uma arquitetura limpa
Seria mais vantagens de utilizar o $transaction em querys de SELECT em vez de usar o Promise.all? Se sim, quais?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não existe vantagem em usar Transaction nesse caso, o uso do Promise.All deve ser mais rápido por não precisar da lógica adicional da transação, o que você poderia fazer, mas é opcional, é simplesmente ter um metodo na service que fizesse tanto o count quanto o findMany usando Promise.all, mas isso é questão de gosto. Seu código já está ótimo.

Recomendo usar transaction apenas quando uma transação realmente depender da outra, como quando você precisa atualizar duas tabelas relacionadas, e caso dê algum erro e atualize apenas uma os dados ficariam incosistentes, nesse caso é vantagem usar transaction para não ter dados incosistentes.